# Is there a function to debug several bugs that are exactly the same?

Tags: google-apps-script

*I wrote a VERY long code. I found an error in my code. I debugged it, but I found out that I had made that same bug once every 75 lines of code or so. And I wrote about 52,093 lines of code. Please tell me there is an easier way to debug all the errors!

`SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`
        
`` `5765` /loc/
`6196` /loc/ ``

Comment: You might be able to move it to an editor like ultraedit and use regular expressions to find and fix many of the errors.

Comment: You shouldn't have wrote that many lines, if it is simply repitition of the same concept

Comment: It depends on the change you need to make every 75 lines. If it's just replacing one sequence of characters for another (and if this sequence is only repeated in these "bugs"), `Find and replace...`. If not, you might have to something else, like @Cooper said. If you have doubts, I'd suggest you to give more information on the error you have to fix.

Comment: Also, if this bug is repeated every 75 lines, you are probably repeating the same actions many times, and you could use a loop for that. I seriously doubt you need 52,093 lines of code.

Comment: I think the consensus among all of us that have read this question is that the the best course of action is to rewrite the script entirely.  My guess is that we all feel like we could have done that same script in less than 100 lines. So I’d recommend rewriting and avoid the use of activate, setActivePage and any other commands that are commonly found on macros. Read best practices in the support page of documentation

Answer (score 0):

As  Cooper says: Editors have Find & replace. But no need to copy out the code, fix it and return it back.
Apps Script own editor IDE, has Find & Replace function. Hit Ctrl+F and fill in the Buggy code to find ... and the correct one to Replace.

Good Luck.!